# Get User Facebook Shares from Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a Facebook app and the ability to use the Facebook Graph API or FQL with valid access tokens for each of my users. The permission includes read_stream.

My goal is to search the user's timeline for content they have shared from specific Facebook pages. This is for a game: users will be rewarded points for sharing page content. This means if they click the "share" button on anything the page has posted: links, albums, photos, and status updates, and post it to their wall.

Requesting the shares directly from the page only provides a Share Count, not any information on the users that shared the content.
**/[page_id]/posts?fields=shares**

Using FQL to query the user's stream for posts with the via_id set to the Page ID only gives me some shares (it misses photo shares and status shares, among others)-- and no identifying information on the original page post (all of these IDs are either the user or null)
**SELECT post_id, parent_post_id, source_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND via_id = [page_id]**

Using the Graph API to query the user's posts also lacks data on the original page post, so there is no way to determine the source of the shared_story. the story_tags sometimes contain the id of the originating page. The object_id is also sometimes set to the id of the originating post, but again, not always.
**/me/posts**

Is there something I am missing, or another approach I could take? To me it seems that there is some missing functionality in the Facebook API, since share posts have a unique type but most just don't have the identifying information from the source content. The relationship must be there because on the Facebook interface, it links directly to the source.

Thanks